# Need info on how to create a Batch file to edit multiple html files

Tags: html, image, batch-file, edit

My file structure and procedure goes like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYy1M.jpg

- I have a folder named "Project_ID".
- Inside that folder, I have my html files and another folder that contains my design templates named 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg and so on...
- In those html files, I make previews of each photo, e.g. 01.html, 02.html, 03.html and so on...
- If you click and open 01.html, you see the first image 01.jpg. If you click on that image, it sends you to the same folder at the file "02.html" that opens 02.jpg and so on until you reach the last html that opens the 01.html again.

--------------------------------------…

The thing that I want to "automate" with a batch file is:

Every time I have a new project, I have to go inside each .html file with notepad, change the value "Profile" inside Profile, with the exact name my initial folder has (Project_ID).

Then, I have to replace width (in my example 1920) and height (in my example 2394), with the exact dimensions of my 01.jpg in the images folder.

Of course, I would like to have my batch to create all those .html files with notepad from scratch by looking first "The name of the initial folder (Project_ID)", "the number of my .jpg files in the images folder" and then creating the exact number of the html files that are needed for the functionality I explained at the start. I guess it would be a bit hard to do with just a batch file.

Anyone can help?

Comment: is there a reason you don't use a serverside or even client side programming solution that does all of that automatically? is it targeted to dekstop, or to the internet/intranet?

Comment: @hexblot: Judging from his cute attempt at not letting to save the image, the latter.

Comment: @himself: it didn't even get to me that this was an attempt to prevent image saving :P

Answer (score 0):

That's a pain to do. Consider other approaches:

- Write one HTML page which loads and displays different images with javascript. Then you don't have to change anything except for project name.
- Write one PHP script which returns different images, then call it like this: `display.php?project=MyProject&img=1`
- At the very least, use something reasonable such as python.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to create a photo gallery, I strongly suggest you have a look at [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/en/).  It will generate your web album with just a few clicks, has a plethora of [community-developed templates](http://jalbum.net/en/skins/new;jsessionid=1iae70brab19w1gdon3ije6eo2), and you can even generate slide shows with it.  If preventing right-click saving of your images is your primary goal, I think there are templates that display images using Flash Player.

Check out a few [sample albums](http://jalbum.net/en/explore/featured) and see what you think.

---

If you insist on using your own templates, look into inline stream editing with [GnuWin32 sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).  You can change your project in all the html pages using regexps like this:

```
sed -i -r -e "s/Profile/Project_ID/g" *.html
```

and perform similar modifications with your image widths.

However, GnuWin32 `sed`'s inline editing tends to leave garbage temp files with randomly generated names in its wake when using the `-i` switch.  Might be better to use a `for` loop and redirect the output of `sed` like this:

```
for %%I in (*.html) do (
    sed -r -e "s/Profile/Project_ID/g" %%I >%%I.temp
    move /y %%I.temp %%I
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Get directory from cmdline
SET sourcedir=%~1
IF NOT DEFINED sourcedir ECHO Require source directory&GOTO :EOF 
IF NOT exist "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" ECHO No JPGs found IN %sourcedir%&GOTO :EOF
::
:: get name of project (last element in path)
::
FOR %%i IN ("%~1") DO SET project=%%~ni
ECHO project is %project%
:: Create subdir for HTMLs
SET "newhtmls=%sourcedir%\newhtmls"
MD "%newhtmls%" 2>NUL
::
:: %2 is the name of a file containing .jpg names in the order
:: in which they are to appear. 
::
:: If %2 is missing, create a list file
SET imgseqlist=%2
IF DEFINED imgseqlist GOTO haveseq
SET imgseqlist=%temp%\htmlfilelist.txt
SET dellist="%imgseqlist%"
DIR /b /a-d /ON "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" >"%imgseqlist%"
:haveseq
::
:: Build file of image details
:: I use IRFANVIEW
::
SET imgdetails=%temp%\imagedetails.txt
SET dellist=%dellist% "%imgdetails%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\irfanview\i_view32.exe" "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" /info="%imgdetails%"
::
:: Now let's process
::
(SET firstimg=)
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i IN ("%imgseqlist%") DO (
IF DEFINED firstimg (SET nextimg=%%i&CALL :generate) ELSE (SET firstimg=%%i)
(SET currimg=%%i)
)
:: Do the last one...
SET nextimg=%firstimg%
CALL :generate

:: And finally delete the tempfile
DEL %dellist%

GOTO :EOF 

:generate
:: output filename=current imagename -last 4 chars (.jpg)
SET outfile=%currimg:~0,-4%.html
SET nexthtml=%nextimg:~0,-4%.html
::
:: Look up the details of your image.
:: using IRFANVIEW format
::
(SET setdetails=)
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,4,6" %%d IN ("%imgdetails%") DO (
IF DEFINED setdetails IF "%%e"=="dimensions" (SET width=%%f&SET height=%%g&SET setdetails=)
IF /i %%d==[%nextimg%] SET setdetails=Y
)
:: I'd have filled out these details if you'd posted them
:: rather than just a picture :(
>%newhtmls%\%outfile% (
ECHO ^<!DOCTYPE...transitional.dtd"^>
ECHO ^<html...xthml"^>
ECHO ^<head^>
ECHO ^<meta...-8" /^>
ECHO ^<title^>%project^</title^>
ECHO ^<...and so ON...^>
ECHO         background-image:url(images/%currimg%^);
ECHO ^<...and so ON...^>
ECHO ^</head^>
ECHO.
ECHO ^<body^>
ECHO ^<a href="%nexthtml%"^>^<img src="images/blank.gif" width="%width%" height="%height%" /^>^</a^>
ECHO ^</body^>
ECHO ^</html^>
)
GOTO :eof
```